# Improve pandas filter speed by storing indices?

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'ID2':[2,6,6,2,1,2],'AREA':[1,1,1,1,1,1]})
...

    ID1 ID2 AREA
0   1   2   1
1   2   6   1
2   3   6   1
3   4   2   1
4   5   1   1
5   6   2   1
```

I accumulate the AREA column as so:

```
for id_ in df.ID1:   
    id1_filter = df.ID1 == id_
    id2_filter = (df.ID1 == id_) | (df.ID2 == id_)
    df.loc[id1_filter, 'AREA'] = df.loc[id2_filter].AREA.sum()

print(df)
...
ID1 ID2 AREA
0   1   2   2
1   2   6   5
2   3   6   1
3   4   2   1
4   5   1   1
5   6   2   7
```

For each `id_` in `ID1`, the `AREA` is summed where `ID1` == `id_` or `ID2 == id_`, 
and it is always run when `df` is sorted on `ID1`.

The real dataframe I'm working on though is 150,000 records, each row belonging to a unique ID1.
Running the above on this dataframe takes 2.5 hours.  Since this operation will take place repeatedly
for the foreseeable future, I decided to store the indices of the True values in `id1_filter` and `id2_filter`
in a DB with the following schema.

**Table ID1:**

```
ID_,INDEX_
1  ,   0
2  ,   1
etc, ect
```

**Table ID2:**

```
ID_,INDEX_
1  ,   0
1  ,   4
2  ,   0
2  ,   1
2  ,   3
2  ,   5
etc, etc
```

The next time I run the accumulation on the `AREA` column (now filled with different `AREA` values)
I read in the sql tables and the convert them to dicts.  I then use these dicts
to grab the records I need during the summing loop.

```
id1_dict = pd.read_sql('select * from ID1',db_engine).groupby('ID_').INDEX_.unique().to_dict()
id2_dict = pd.read_sql('select * from ID2',db_engine).groupby('ID_').INDEX_.unique().to_dict()

# print indices for id1_filter and id2_fillter for id 1
print(id1_dict[1])
print(id2_dict[1])
...
[0]
[0, 4]

 for id_ in df.ID1:
        df.loc[id1_dict[id_], 'AREA'] = df.loc[id2_dict[id_]].AREA.sum()
```

When run this way it only takes 6 minutes!

My question: Is there a better/standard way to handle this scenario, i.e  storing dataframe selections for 
later use?  Side note, I have set an index on the SQL table's ID columns and tried getting the
indices by querying the table for each id, and it works well, but still takes a little longer than the above (9 mins).

Comment: I have a question, for the column AREA after running your code once, you have 5 for the second row. It means that it uses the value of AREA at the first row already updated right and equal to 2, not 1 anymore?

Comment: Correct.  The dataframe will always need to be run in that order, aka, sometimes AREA will be calculated using previously summed 'AREA' values.  This is what is supposed to happen, I just need to be able to do it faster.

Comment: ok, another quetion then, the ID2 will always be linked to the same ID1 or it will change? (not sure I understood the read sql table of your question)

Comment: All ID2 ids are found in the ID1 column, and a given ID2 id can be associated with many different ID1 records (up to 71).  The ID1 column is a series of unique ids, aka, my df has a len(df) of 150000, which means 150000 unique ids in ID1.  Its a bit confusing, but you can see it in the initial example df I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is like this:

```
df = df.set_index('ID1') 
for row in df.join(df.groupby('ID2')['AREA'].apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist()),rsuffix='_').dropna().itertuples():
    df.loc[row[0],'AREA'] += df.loc[row[3],'AREA'].sum()
df = df.reset_index()
```

and you get the result expected

```
   ID1  ID2  AREA
0    1    2     2
1    2    6     5
2    3    6     1
3    4    2     1
4    5    1     1
5    6    2     7
```

Now on a bigger `df` like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'ID1':range(1,1501),'ID2': np.random.randint(1,1501,(1500,)),'AREA':[1]*1500}, 
                   columns = ['ID1','ID2','AREA'])
```

The method presented here turns in about 0.76 s on my computer while your first is running in 6.5 s.

Ultimately, you could create a `df_list` such as:

```
df_list = (df.set_index('ID1')
             .join(df.set_index('ID1').groupby('ID2')['AREA']
                     .apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist()),rsuffix='_ID2')
             .dropna().drop(['AREA','ID2'],1))
```

to keep somewhere the information that linked ID1 and ID2: here you can see the id is equal to 2 in the column ID2, where the value of ID1 = 1, 4 and 6

```
      AREA_ID2
ID1           
1          [5]
2    [1, 4, 6]
6       [2, 3]
```

and then you can run to not re-create the `df_list`, with a small difference in the code:

```
df = df.set_index('ID1') 
for row in df_list.itertuples():
    df.loc[row[0],'AREA'] += df.loc[row[1],'AREA'].sum()
df = df.reset_index()
```

Hope it's faster

Comment: This is it!  It only take 3min to run the whole shebang.  I learned a lot from this code, and it pointed out some glaring inefficiencies to me.